# Missing light sensor events but hardware seems to see them

Tags: gpio, gpiozero

My configuration is a a red laser (5V) and a light sensor (Dollatek) which outputs a HIGH signal if no light is detected. Using a potentiometer the sensitivity can be adjusted.
I set it so that the slightest interruption of the light beam will trigger the sensor. The sensor board has an LED that turns off if no light is detected.

No matter how fast I interrupt the laser beam, the light will turn off and back on. If I write a test app using `gpiozero` (see code below) it will show me dozens of events, even the ones where an object passed the light barrier at very high speed.

```py
...

def button_pressed(button):
    global count
    print(f"{count} Button on pin {button.pin.number} was pressed")
    count = count + 1

...

button = Button(pin, pull_up = False, bounce_time = None, hold_time = 0)
button.when_pressed = lambda captured_button = button: button_pressed(captured_button)
```

Notice how I am **not** using the `LightSensor` class because the sensor board acts like a button and outputs a binary value.

With all working as expected, I integrated my code into a Pygame. The main loop blits a full HD image (the same, loaded once at the beginning) on each iteration.

My observation is that sometimes, the interruption of the laser beam won't be detected. Even for objects much slower than what I used in my tests. And we're talking about one single event every now and then. My suspicion is that it has something to do with the fact that now, the Raspberry 4 has to run a graphical interface and not just a simple console app. Can someone explain what might be going on, what I could still try?

Comment: No context.  Need code listing.  Need details of Pi.